# how to use the form(checkbox) to pass the user id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-request

> I have a table in it there are checkboxes I need that on those users
>   on which the checkbox is selected their id was transferred

***my form***

```
<input type="submit" form="qwe">
 <form action="{{URL::to('othet_nn')}}" method="get" id="qwe">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="id">
             </form>
```

***my controller***

```
public function chek(){
        dd($_GET);
        return view('admin.pages.othet_test');
    }
```

> I need to be passed the id of those users who had a check mark in the
>   checkbox

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests

Answer (score 1):

you can use this like

```
 <form action="{{URL::to('othet_nn')}}" method="post" id="qwe">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="1">
             </form>
public function check(Request $request){
        dd($request->id);
        return view('admin.pages.othet_test');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you should use Request class. To see the whole input you can use:

```
request()->all()
```

and to get individual field you can use

```
request()->input('id')
```

I advise you to read [documentation about requests](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#retrieving-input)

Comment: you mean 
`$request->id` or `$request->input('name')`